# Find multiple occurrences of different URLs in a big string, where each URL is between two specific substrings using Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file containing just one long string which has multiple URLs embedded in it. The URLs are all different but are always enclosed between two specific substrings. How can I extract all the URLs?

My File Contents look like the following:

```
data-starred-src="www.example.com" data-non-starred-src asdf asdf ghgh data-starred-src="www.someurl.com" data-non-starred-src gjsltg ajshssl ahssfh data-starred-src="www.anotherurl.com" data-non-starred-src
```

I want to extract URLs in the form

```
www.example.com
www.someurl.com
www.anotherurl.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(?<=\")([^"]+\.[^"]+\.[^"]+)(?=\")
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/sI2jL7

or another example:

http://regex101.com/r/sI2jL7

Comment: That is fine but there is other stuff in the string in double quotes as well. I have updated the question to add the exact delimiting strings.

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar, I don't know what you mean, look at my example links,- my regex matches both your original example AND your edited example.. What is not matching or working as expected with my regex?

Comment: Yes, just used it, it works with my file. Although there is one strange thing that I'm getting along with the URLs. A lot of empty braces such as [ ] [ ] if I write the output to file

Comment: Okay, figured the issue with out

Answer (score 2):

On the example, this one:

```
print re.findall(r'data-starred-src\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"', line)
```

*Gives:*

```
['www.example.com', 'www.someurl.com', 'www.anotherurl.com']
```

Comment: Your answer both covers the widest cases and is the most readable.  By far the best

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import re
r1 = re.compile('(?:AAA ")([^"]*)(?:" BBB)')
s = 'AAA "www.example.com" BBB asdf asdf ghgh AAA "www.someurl.com" BBB gjsltg ajshssl ahssfh AAA "www.anotherurl.com" BBB'
res = r1.findall(s)
```

You may also consider using `finditer()` if `s` is really long.

Updated re looks like this

```
r1 = re.compile('(?:data-starred-src=")([^"]*)(?:" data-non-starred-src)')
```

but I've simply replaced AAA and BBB with new delimiters so it's possible that the code won't work if it didn't work before.

Comment: This looks workable but the problem is that the string also has other things enclosed in quotes, perhaps using something like a http and .com may be workable. Let me give it a try

Comment: You should precisely specify what the delimiters are. If you do, then the regexp can be adjusted to match that particular case. BTW I updated the answer and now it checks for AAA and BBB.

Comment: Tried the above but getting empty braces on the output. The string is definitely very long. So perhaps finditer is the right way

Comment: Updated the question to add the exact delimiting strings

Comment: Then likely you operate on a string of a slightly different format, which is unknown for us. So if you wish to receive a helpful answer you should specify the conditions more precisely. I would suggest to test the provided solution(s) on a short substring of the real input, assure that the code works and then accurately inspect the input to find where it differs in structure from the substring.